# datetime picker for ASP.NET 3.5 webforms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datetime, .net-3.5, asp.net-ajax

Is there a free for commercial use date and time picker in ASP.NET webforms?

Right now I am using the AJAX calender extender with Visual studio 2008, but have nothing for time picker.

I want a control that is free and has no license to it. I know that there are JavaScript controls but was wanting to stick with ASP.NET webforms controls, as I am not good with JavaScript.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is the best I've found on the interwebs. [Date picker widgit](http://www.frequency-decoder.com/2009/09/09/unobtrusive-date-picker-widget-v5)

I really would not recommend using ASP.Net's WebForms built in support for javascript/date pickers, but that's just me.

If you **really** need to stick with ASP.Net. There's an [ajax control](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) for you.

**Edit**
Here's a [time picker.](http://haineault.com/media/examples/jquery-utils/demo/ui-timepickr.html) If you don't like JS, I could codify a control for you in an hour ;).

Comment: i am already using the ajax control but that does not allow me to chose time or make any changes in time.. i am more concerned about getting the time... like in one textbox and an arrow on the side..

Comment: if you could do that it would be great.. but will i be use it in my application.... and of commercial use... thanks